# Widget outputting JS as plain text

Tags: widgets, javascript

I have made a custom widget that works in a shortcode but when i go to use it as a widget the javascript involved in the output is shown as plain text.

How do i make a widget output javascript as javascript not plain text?

Comment: Do you know Google? [Let me google for you](http://bfy.tw/Akua).

Comment: @MaxYudin if you kindly stop being an asshole and actually read the question you would realise its about a custom coded widget not some off the shelf widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to put propper `<script>`tags around your code?

So instead of inserting the raw JS code, I suppose you encapsule the code it like this:

```
<script>
// JS goes here
</script>
```

This at least works with the common `text` widget.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to work if i encapsulated outside of the function that outputs the JS

Comment: Great. Thank you for letting me know that it worked! :)